# How to click on the red "X" and minimize the app instead of closing it?

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

To close my app I have been using:

```
on applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:sender
        return true
    end applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:
```

I would like that when I click on the red "X" the application is not closed just minimize or hide to the Dock so when I click it I can open it again.

Comment: Generally speaking, the red 'x' button is meant to close the window entirely (and in some cases close the app, if it's a one-window app). To minimize a window, you should use the orange '-' button. This is standard on OSX, and is hard-wired into the window object in an xib. If you try to change the behavior, you'll give yourself a headache and confuse users. If the minimize button isn't active on your window, it would be far easier to activate it than to try to change the behavior of the close button.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but in some apps clicking the red close button closes only the window and not the app itself. That's what I wanted to try, thanks, @TedWrigley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the following method in the application delegate to control whether the application closes when the last window is closed:

```
on applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:theSendingApp
    -- this keeps the application running
    return false 
end applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:
```

Depending on the kind of app you've designed and the kind of window you're using, the app may or may not reopen its window when you reactivate it (e.g., when click on the dock item). You may need to add another method to the app delegate to handle that case:

```
on applicationShouldHandleReopen:theSendingApp hasVisibleWindows:openWindowFlag
    if openWindowFlag is true then
        return true
    else
        theWindow's makeKeyAndOrderFront:me
        return true
    end if
end applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:
```

`theWindow` refers to the property in the app delegate that holds the widow reference (I believe that's what Xcode names it in the default implementation). You should check the window object in the xib: look in the Attributes Inspector and make sure the checkbox 'Released when closed' is *off*. You want to retain the window after it's closed so that you can open it again.